# How to create a phylogenetic tree (using Maximum Likelihood method) in newick format for a Multiple Sequence Alignment file in FASTA format?

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogenetics

The file size is really big (26.7 MB). So, I am unable to use the online web tools, as they cannot handle such large input data.

Comment: Look into [IQ-TREE](http://www.iqtree.org/). If you can work with `R`, I'd recommend `phangorn` to do the maximum likelihood analysis, and use `write.tree()` from `ape` to write the Newick tree(s).

Answer (score 1):

[RAxML](https://cme.h-its.org/exelixis/software.html) ([Stamatakis, 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3998144/)) would be a good place to start.